# Why is it slow: "SELECT * ... ORDER BY id LIMIT 50000, 2"

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

`car_trims` is an InnoDB table, has ~40 fields, average row length is 230 bytes, no TEXT or BLOB type columns

`car_trims.id` is PK

**Query 1**: .0007 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM car_trims ORDER BY id LIMIT 2
```

**Query 2**: .023 seconds

```
SELECT id FROM car_trims ORDER BY id LIMIT 50000, 2
```

**Query 3**: .09 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM car_trims ORDER BY id LIMIT 50000, 2
```

First off, I don't understand why query 2 is so slow, but it's marginally acceptable. What I really don't get is why query 3 is taking nearly 100ms to read the row data using the primary key.

My understanding is that the database should be retrieving the PK from memory to locate the row on disk and then read it out. Query 3 shouldn't be taking much longer than query 1.

**EXPLAIN**

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
 1       SIMPLE     car_trims     NULL  index   NULL            PRIMARY       4     NULL    50002   100.00      NULL
```

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
sql_mode = "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_type=0
#query_cache_limit  = 1M
#query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem


# Custom Stuff
performance-schema=0
event_scheduler=ON
slow-query-log=1
long-query-time=1
max_user_connections=1000
max_connections=1100
table_open_cache=8192
key_buffer_size=64M #myisam table index buffer
max_connect_errors=20
max_allowed_packet=256M
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=256M
tmp_table_size=256M
thread_cache_size=100

concurrent_insert=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_file_size=32M            #see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-and-removing.html
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_stats_on_metadata=off
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=10000
```

Comment: How about a `SHOW CREATE TABLE car_trims\g`?

Comment: If there is not enough (available) memory, than query3 will always take more time than query1 because those 50000 records need to be skipped.   To improve speed you can try `OPTIMIZE TABLE car_trims`.  If this helps, you need to do it when 'a lot of changes'  have been done to this table.

Comment: Which query is that `EXPLAIN` for?

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` is for Query 3

Comment: As documented in the explain for query 3, the system had to munge through 50000 rows (your request) to then deliver 2 rows of data.  What makes you think this should be 'FAST'?  Please post the result of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';  your max_connections is likely OVERPROVISIONED AT ~ 1000.  If you DELETE read_buffer_size and read_rnd_buffer_size and let the DEFAULTS work for you, likely response time would be better.

Comment: @Dan Any news you could share on your progress?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB now... not so much for the performance, but for the flexibility. But here's an interesting optimization: `SELECT * FROM car_trims
WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM car_trims ORDER BY id LIMIT 50000,1)
LIMIT 2` the result of Query 3 at the speed of Query 2. Seems to me this type of optimization should be built-in to MySQL. Perhaps it is in versions > 5.7

Comment: @Dan Please post the EXPLAIN SELECT .....(your last example on Dec 2); so we can all observe how a slightly different query reduces the ROWS touched.